# Two onCreateDialogs

Tags: android

Im trying to use both datepicker and timepicker.I am a newbie in android. The problem is the two onCreateDialogs. Eclipce ask me to rename the second one. But when i do that, timepicker doesnt show up. What is the problem?
Thanks in advance

// Datepicker

```
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID=0;
    int yr,mon,day;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v)
    {
         Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
         yr=today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         mon=today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         day=today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,dateSetListener,yr,mon,day);

        }
        return null;
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            yr=year;
            mon=monthOfYear+1;
            day=dayOfMonth;
            EditText it=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            it.setText(day+" - "+mon+" - "+yr);
        }


    };      

  //Timepicker

    int hour,min;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=1;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showTimeDialog(View v) {
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        min=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog1(int id)
    {
        switch(id)
        {
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, hour, min,true);
        }
        return null;
    }
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hour=hourOfDay;
            min=minute;
            EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textTime);
            et.setText(hour+" : "+min);

        }


    };

    //
```

Comment: You should combine the two `onCreateDialog()` methods into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your switch statements in the onCreateDialog as:

```
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,dateSetListener,yr,mon,day);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeSetListener, hour, min,true);
```

This way the appropriate dialog will pop up depending on  the input.

Comment: thanks. I tried this but then there is another issue. In xml i have two separate editexts, one for datepicker and one for timepicker. Both two dialogs show up in first edittext....

Comment: @user3649152, As you mentioned it above, it is another question, so please start a new thread for it (if you can't find the answer here). Each thread should solve a single problem, not fulfill every request of the op. If the solution worked for you, accept the answer so the thread can be closed, and others may learn from it too.